# A word that describes something that evokes something?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the sun may evoke an existential angst.

How could I phrase it like **"The ___ sun"**, where ___ is a word that could succinctly communicate my sentiment.

Comment: I'm a little confused; something which evokes a feeling is *evocative*. Is that what you're looking for, or do you want a word which means to evoke something specific, like your "*existential angst*" example? (And does the Sun really make you feel *bad*? Always cheers me up!)

Comment: @DanBron is right. *Evocative* is the catch-all term. If you need to be more specific than that, by all means be more specific.

Comment: The "sullen" sun ...

Comment: Another s**t day loomed ahead as the sun rose. (Little Eva's “a/another sullen day” would sound more poetic)

Comment: Thank you, dear. But yours @Mari-Lou, is far more tangible.

Comment: This question sounds like a drunken Stephen Fry wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking for a word that refers to the evocation of something negative:

[Disquieting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disquieting):

> - causing mental discomfort. 
>     *Disquieting thoughts echo deep in my soul.*

[Perturbing:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perturbing)

> - causing distress or worry or anxiety;

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Further: ominous, threatening, for bearing, disturbing, unsettling...

Comment: The *perturbing* sun? How can a sun be perturbing? I have never heard of a sun being described like that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  well, if the sun exerts a negative influence on you awakening bad memomies or anxieties ...it may well be described with a number of unusual adjectives that one does not  commonly associate with it.  (that is what I undestood from the question)